# Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests : Magento2.3

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

I am facing issue when enabling elastic search in magento 2.3 with latest elastic version 7.3.1. All products are hidden in frontend and search not working and when trying to do manual indexing getting this error.

> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types
>   cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the
>   include_type_name parameter is set to
>   true."}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Types cannot be
>   provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name
>   parameter is set to true."},"status":400}

Comment: Hey, Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 9):

Go to `Magento\Elasticsearch6\Model\Client\Elasticsearch`

Find function `addFieldsMapping` approx line number 241

Add new element to `$params` array

```
'include_type_name' => true,
```

This will resolve your error

```
$params = [
    'index' => $index,
    'type' => $entityType,
    'include_type_name' => true,
```

Answer (score 2):

**Types** in requests is deprecated in Elasticsearch 7.x version.

- Types are deprecated in APIs in 7.x, with breaking changes to the
  index creation, put mapping, get mapping, put template, get template
  and get field mappings APIs.
- For instance, indexing a document no longer requires a document type.
  The new index APIs are `PUT {index}/_doc/{id}` in case of explicit
  ids and `POST {index}/_doc` for auto-generated ids.

  Note that in 7.0, `_doc` is a permanent part of the path, and
  represents the endpoint name rather than the document type.
- The `include_type_name` parameter in the index creation, index
  template, and mapping APIs will default to false. Setting the
  parameter at all will result in a deprecation warning.
- The `_default_` mapping type is removed.

Switching to Elasticsearch 6.x is one of the best alternative as this will be endpoint update for the elastic search libraries (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php).

It can be achievable to use include_type_name is an elastic search flag but it will attract a deprecated warning.

For debugging purpose, one should make a change in the methods (i.e. `addFieldsMapping`, `deleteMapping` ) of the following class by creating a override module for `elasticsearchfix-7`.

```
vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch-6/Model/Client/Elasticsearch.php
```

Comment: the solution right now is to only downgrade the version to 6.*, other than that i don't found any solution.

Comment: Hello @Sandip. Do you know how to compatible elasticsearch 7 version? Which changes should I need to add?

Comment: A Separate module is needed like Magento/ElasticSearch6 with `composer require "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "~7.6",` into main `composer.json` file

Answer (score 2):

This has fixed the problem `Types cannot be provided in put mapping requests, unless the include_type_name parameter is set to true.` for me in Magento 2.4.2-p1:

```
n98-magerun2.phar  config:store:set  catalog/search/engine  elasticsearch7
n98-magerun2.phar  config:store:set  catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname  '<elastic_host>'
n98-magerun2.phar  cache:clean  config
```

If you don't have `n98-magerun2.phar` installed, [more info can be found here](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2#download-and-install-phar-file). You can also [switch to ElasticSearch 7 using the Admin interface](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-elasticseach-in-magento-2.html#step-1).

Comment: Instead of `n98-magerun2.phar`, you could use magento default command, Ex: `n98-magerun2.phar  config:store:set  catalog/search/engine  elasticsearch7`, you could use `php bin/magento config:set catalog/search/engine 'elasticsearch7' ` instead.

Comment: Also, set elastic search to correct version worked for me. In my case, it was elasticsearch7, you could set in Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.